# Can't find psqlrc file for Postgresql on Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql

Kind of new to IT and trying to learn Postgresql. I was having a problem where my SQL commands weren't outputting to the psql prompt. This was fixed with `\pset pager off`

That's great! Problem is I have to type it in every time I open the prompt. So I heard about a psqlrc.conf file where I can set variables. Problem is I can't find it.

I tried following this guide - https://mladenuzelac.blogspot.com/2016/01/psqlrc-in-windows.html, but no Postgresql folder exists under `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\postgresql`.

I've added both the bin and lib to the path successfully as well, for both the system and user. Not sure what I'm doing wrong at this point :).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Simply create one in `%appdata%\postgresql`.
Rule of thumb is if you know a process uses a configuration file, and you can not find that file, you can just make one yourself.

There is also an important distinction between Linux and Windows psqlrc files that needs to be noted:

- On Linux `psql` uses `~/.psqlrc` file;
- On Windows - `%appdata%\postgresql\psqlrc.conf`.

(note the difference of `.` and `.conf`).

Comment: I'll give this a try Pawel and let you know how it goes!

Comment: So I did that, created the postgresql directory in appdata then the conf file but still no luck. Is there another step I'm missing for the file to take effect?

Comment: Weird, it should work out-of-the-box. You can try the following: 1. restart terminal instance; 2. Check if `PSQLRC` env variable is set with `Get-Item -Path Env:PSQLRC` in PowerShell; If it's not, set it with `$Env:PSQLRC = "C:\Users\<your-username>\AppData\Roaming\postgresql\psqlrc.conf"`.

Comment: Ya no luck my friend. Maybe windows isnt the best environment for this. When I start building it on centos I'll start looking at it more seriously. Even loaded up a fresh windows 10 VM with nothing on it and still doesn't work.